# Required lifetime parameter on array of vec

Tags: rust

So everytime I run this :

```rust
static LAYERS_NB : u32 = 50;

struct Layers{
    layers: [Vec<render::Texture>;LAYERS_NB],
}
```

I get this error :

```rust
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/display.rs:12:18
   |
12 |     layers: [Vec<render::Texture>;LAYERS_NB],
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Texture is a structure from the SDL2 wrapper library of Rust. I don't understand why he is asking me a lifetime since my Struct doesn't own any references.
Can somebody explain me why ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, [`sdl2::render::Texture`](https://rust-sdl2.github.io/rust-sdl2/sdl2/render/struct.Texture.html) does have a lifetime parameter, so your struct containing it also has to have one. And the size of an array needs to be a constant `usize`:

```
const LAYERS_NB: usize = 50;

struct Layers<'a> {
    layers: [Vec<render::Texture<'a>>; LAYERS_NB],
}
```

The Rust compiler is generally very good at telling you what is wrong. Try read the diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! :)
I must say Rust is a very tough language, any tip is welcome !